# How do vertically center a div?

Tags: css, positioning, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically center my main content div. I am open to using jQuery and/or CSS, but I'd prefer avoiding an extra wrapper div tag.

What do I need to do to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').css('position', 'relative');
    $('#main').css('top', (($('#main').parent().height() - $('#main').height()) / 2) + "px");
});
```

Comment: Ah, so you need a wrapper div. There's no way to do so without it, apparently.

Comment: What should the parent container's height be?

Comment: `#wrap`'s height, you can adjust it or even remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css), which recommends the following article.

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: When I look at the demos on that page, the first one (the 'valid' one) doesn't work in either FF 3.6 or Safari 5 on my Mac. However, the 'final' one does work. I didn't look at all the variations.